# Lines in rake routes with no HTTP verb

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, http-verbs

What does it mean when there are no HTTP verbs next to the URL pattern?  For example, when I type

```
 rake routes
```

Here's a snippet of what I see:

```
PUT     /articles/:id
DELETE  /articles/:id
        /articles/:id/:article_page
        /articles/:id/:show_full
```

Notice lines 3 and 4 have no http verb.  Do I assume it defaults to GET?

By the way, I'm working on a Rails 2.3.18 project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means that the route is accessible via all verbs.

This is not recommended and since Rails 4, you are encouraged to specify a verb.

Indeed, in Rails 4, you **must** explicitly mention `via: :all`:

```
match 'hello', to: 'dashboard#hello', via: :all
```